# C# Get random integer from list in each loop

Tags: c#, random

I'm new to C# and have the following piece of code:

```
int[] ids = { 190483, 184943, 192366, 202556, 169051, 177388, 170890, 146562, 189509 };

for (var i=0; i<50; i++)
{
    int randomID = *randomNumberFromIDList*;
    Console.WriteLine("Random ID:" + randomID);
}
```

As you can see, all I'm looking to do is with each loop assign and display a random ID from the list with the randomID being set as an int.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You'll need an instance of `Random` class, say it's named `random`. Then just call `random.Next(ids.Count)` and use it as an index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `Random` instance and call the `Next(int, int)` function to get number between `inclusive lowest number` and `exclusive highest number`:

```
int[] ids = { 190483, 184943, 192366, 202556, 169051, 177388, 170890, 146562, 189509 };

var random = new Random();
for (var i=0; i<50; i++)
{
    int randomID = ids[random.Next(0, ids.Length)];
    Console.WriteLine("Random ID:" + randomID);
}
```

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri As stated the second argument is the _exclusive_ upper bound. Therefor `Next(0, 1)` will always generate `0`. See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Random` class for this and generate random number between 0 and length of an array:

```
var r = new Random();   
for (var i=0; i<50; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("Random ID:" + ids[r.Next(0, ids.Length)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a random to generate a index starting from 0 to the size of your array, with this index you acess a position of your array and get a random ID.

```
int[] ids = { 190483, 184943, 192366, 202556, 169051, 177388, 170890, 146562, 189509 };

var random = new Random();

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
     int arrayPos = random.Next(0, ids.Count() - 1);
     int randomID = ids[arrayPos];
     Console.WriteLine("Random ID:" + randomID);
}
```